# Increasing row height in R heatmap() function

Tags: r, data-visualization

I have a matrix with hundreds of rows and tens of columns and wish to plot a heatmap. If I use the native R function:

```
heatmap(matrix(sample(1:10000),nrow=1000,ncol=10))
```

I get a figure with illegible row titles. I assume the image is produced to match the specifications of the current plotting device. I'd like control over the height of the rows, even if this can't be displayed on my current device. Simply writing to a tall PNG just adds whitespace above/below the image:

```
png( '/looks_the_same_with_whitespace.png', width=500, height=1500)
heatmap(matrix(sample(1:10000),nrow=1000,ncol=10))
dev.off()
```

Is there a clean way to do this, perhaps by fooling R into thinking I have a very tall monitor? A function from a well-supported library is also a fine answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A while ago, I also faced the same problem. `heatmap.2` function from `gplots` package solved the problem. However, I don't quite see how looking at so many genes (or rowlabs) is beneficial. But as you asked you would do something like this: The key is change the `layout` (see ?heatmap.2, ?layout) of the heatmap which draws heatmap on a 2x2 grid on the plotting device (the example in ?layout explains this much better). After that, you may want to change the `cex` of `rowlabs` by changing `cexRow` accordingly. Your situation might need a bit of playing around with the values to get the desired result.

```
library(gplots)

row.scaled.expr <- matrix(sample(1:10000),nrow=1000,ncol=10)

png( 'heatmap_without_whitespace_smaller_row_lab.png', width=500, height=1500)
heatmap.2(row.scaled.expr, dendrogram ='row',
                 Colv=FALSE, col=greenred(800), 
                 key=FALSE, keysize=1.0, symkey=FALSE, density.info='none',
                 trace='none', colsep=1:10,
                 sepcolor='white', sepwidth=0.05,
                 scale="none",cexRow=0.2,cexCol=2,
                 labCol = colnames(row.scaled.expr),                 
                 hclustfun=function(c){hclust(c, method='mcquitty')},
                 lmat=rbind( c(0, 3), c(2,1), c(0,4) ), lhei=c(0.25, 4, 0.25 ),                 
                 )
dev.off()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Seeing this many rows at once (which are in this case probesets) can be useful during the hypothesis-generating phase of a microarray analysis. Colleagues sometimes request heatmaps of this size, and this makes it easy to zoom through and see which genes are in a sub-cluster.

Comment: can you change the x and y axis labels font size with cex.lab=3? This does not seem to work in for me in the heatmap.2 however cexRow=3 cexCol= 3 works for the values in the heatmap to scale them up.