# How to generate a heatmap with uneven block sizes?

Tags: r

I am using the following code for generating a heat map (out of the AvgByQ vector):

```
library(gplots)
x<-c(0, 5, 30, 80)
y<-c(150, 2000, 2010, 3000)
AvgByQ<-c(20.25, 13.02,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  8.31, 14.66,  0.00)
AvgByQMatrix <- matrix(AvgByQ, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)
heatmap.2(AvgByQMatrix, cellnote=AvgByQMatrix, notecol="black",col=redblue(256),key=TRUE, dendrogram = "none", trace="none")
```

How can I change the block sizes to match/scale to the X and Y vector values?
Also, somewhat-related to the scaling issue, any idea why does the row order (1, 3, 2) gets messed up?
Thanks!

Comment: I am confusing how you would scale your matrix with x and y? x, y are  1x5 vector, and you would scale 3x3 matrix? surely I miss something here.

Comment: the ranges between them, X (5, 25, 50)  Y (1850, 10, 990)

Comment: Thanks, actually found my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040240/increasing-row-height-in-r-heatmap-function

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help you. The following approach has worked for me (although I am only aware of how to do this with the `image()` function:

```
#using image() function
x<-c(0, 5, 30, 80, 1000)
y<-c(150, 2000, 2010, 3000)
grd <- expand.grid(x=x, y=y)
z<-matrix(grd$x*2-grd$y*3, nrow=length(x), ncol=length(y), byrow=TRUE)
image(x=x, y=y, z=z, col=rainbow(20))

#another option with z-scale
source("image.scale.r") #http://menugget.blogspot.de/2011/08/adding-scale-to-image-plot.html
x11(width=5, height=4)
layout(matrix(1:2, nrow=1, ncol=2), widths=c(4,1), heights=4, respect=TRUE)
layout.show(2)
par(mar=c(4,4,1,1))
image(x=x, y=y, z=z, col=rainbow(20))
par(mar=c(4,0,1,4))
image.scale(z, col=rainbow(20), horiz=FALSE, xlab="", ylab="", xaxt="n", yaxt="n")
axis(4)
box()
```

[image]